# Disable DVD-ROM administrative share in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I turned HDD administrative shares off by setting `AutoShareWks=0`, but there are two hidden shares left: `print$` and `W$`. The last represents DVD drive. I can assume that `print$` is necessary for printer sharing, but how to get rid of `W$` ?

Comment: May I ask, why are you trying to remove these shares?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the file manager tool or the **MMC** shared folders tool? If you are using the MMC tool you should have an option to **right-click** and select **"stop sharing",**. hidden or otherwise... is this greyed out?

Comment: It is not only greyed out, it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Check permissions then...I assume you are logged in with full admin rights, but who is the "owner" at the mount point? Can you take ownership? I'm thinking that maybe you don't have the rights to manage the share, that would explain why it is greyed out or not there.